# What is the correct way to find the determinant of the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I found a question in my school textbook (NCERT textbook for Mathematics Part 1 for Class XII). While this question has been answered here, I came across two methods to solve the question, both of which look correct to me, but give two different answers. 
 
The question is: 
 
**If A is an invertible matrix of order 2, then det. $(A^{-1})$ is equal to: 
 
(a) det. (A) 
 
(b) 1/det.() 
 
(c) 1 
 
(d) 0** 
 
The first method to solve (which I could find online elsewhere) is: 
 
**|A|≠0 
 
=> $(A^{-1})$ exists 
 
=> A$(A^{-1})$ = I 
 
|A$(A^{-1})$| = |I| = 1 
 
=> |A||$(A^{-1})$| = 1 
 
|$(A^{-1})$|=1/|| 
 
Hence option (b) is correct.** 
 
The second method (which I used) is: 
 
**$(A^{-1})$ = adj.A/|A| 
 
=> |$(A^{-1})$| = |adj.A|/||A|| 
 
=> |$(A^{-1})$| = $|A|^{n-1}$/|A| where n is the order of the matrix 
 
=> |$(A^{-1})$| = $|A|^{2-1}$/|A| (n is given to be 2) 
 
=> |$(A^{-1})$| = |A|/|A| = 1 
 
Hence option (c) is correct.** 
 
What is wrong with the second method which I used? I tried to find the determinants of many inverses (order 2) but the answer always came out as 1, yet my teacher dismissed my solution.

Comment: Your mistake in the second method is assuming that det $cA$, where $c$ is a constant and $A$ is a matrix, is $c\operatorname{det} A$. This just isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

$$| kA| = k^n |A| $$ where $n$ is the order. In your case, $$ \left | \frac{1}{|A|} \text{adj} A \right |= \left( \frac{1}{|A|} \right)^2 |\text{adj} A| = \left(\frac{1}{|A|^2}\right) |A| = \frac{1}{|A|} $$

Answer (score 0):

For any $2\times2$ invertible matrix,

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

the adjoint is

$$A^*=\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$$ and the inverse

$$A^{-1}=\frac1{\Delta}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac d\Delta&-\dfrac b\Delta\\-\dfrac c\Delta&\dfrac a\Delta\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then

$$\det(A)=\det(A^*)$$ and $$\det(A^{-1})=\frac1{\Delta^2}\det(A^*)=\frac1\Delta.$$